# Как вырезать определенную область картинки и сделать её прозрачной?

Tags: php, изображения

Добрый день.

Как на PHP сделать маску с прозрачным цветом? То есть имеется картинка в формате PNG 150*150 (например, картинка черная со сплошным цветом). Как сделать, чтобы в итоге получилось маска с прозрачностью?

Итоговый результат: http://take.ms/8pmpM

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека GD ([подробный мануал на php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php))

Вырезать кусок изображения [читаем тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopy.php)

Изменение прозрачности [читаем тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php)